# How to off-center Text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm just beginning to learn flutter, and most of the tutorials show you how to center the text on the screen... but what if you want it off-center? For example, a little up for center. How would I do that? (*Thank you in advance!*)

**Edit:**
This is what I have so far, and was wondering if there was an alternative way of achieving the same thing???

```
  body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 100.0,
          child: Text(
            'Text Here',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 36.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: `Align` widget is what you need.

Comment: Maybe add some padding to some sides but not to others, as needed?

Comment: I've updated my question :)

Comment: You don't need to use the center widget. Just for reference check this out https://github.com/arkace-dev/layer_style_app_static . It's one of my basic repo and I've used Text in a completely different setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could eighter use the `Align` widget as @Doc commented, but if you want something a little more specific, you can rap your `Text` widget with a `Padding` widget, with `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB`, and the put say X px in say the right to put the text to the left a little bit.
This gives a little more diversity than `Align` widget, althoug that is really usefull as well

- Little pro tip; Insted of using X px to align it, use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/X to make the app look great on other device-sized too.